# Encontrar um registo usando o valor de um cookie

Tags: php, html, mysqli, sql-select

Eu não consigo encontrar um valor na base de dados por um `select` usando como referência um variável vinda de um *cookie*:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM carrinho WHERE dono = '$dono'";
```

No entanto, se procurar usando o texto da variável,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM carrinho WHERE dono = 'd2466de8-ccde-4939-f756-bf427f'";
```

os valores pretendidos são encontrados.

A variável `$dono` vem de um *cookie*: `$dono = $_COOKIE["id_user"];`

E se der `echo` a variável aparece o mesmo texto `(d2466de8-ccde-4939-f756-bf427f)`

Comment: are you sure if into your browser the cookie exist.

Comment: Estamos no [pt.so], por favor traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: yes the cookie exist if i write echo $_COOKIE["id_user"];
its says d2466de8-ccde-4939-f756-bf427f'

Comment: Dê um echo na variável $query, copie e cole no banco pra testar. Veja se o seu código php está processando essa variável $query de maneira correta, se conecta no banco,se executa a query e traz o resultset. Itere pelo resultset imprimindo os valores na tela.

Comment: @RicardoRoque os parêntesis do valor foi voce que acrescentou ou estao na variavel?

Comment: @Omni nao os parentesis ' ' nao sai da variavél mas mesmo tirando nao corrige

Comment: nao percebo o porque de :
"SELECT * FROM `carrinho` WHERE `dono` LIKE $dono"
ser diferente de:
"SELECT * FROM `carrinho` WHERE `dono` LIKE 'd2466de8-ccde-4939-f756-bf427f'"
quando dando echo de $dono o resultado ser d2466de8-ccde-4939-f756-bf427f

Comment: Tem como colocar seu código completo do banco de dados? Dê um `var_dump($dono)` e coloque aqui **exatamente** o resultado, sem alterar nada.

Comment: o resultado do var_dump foi:
string(36) "d2466de8-ccde-4939-f756-bf427fc4f8fa"

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, será que ele setou o cookie para valer em todo o domínio

Comment: @RicardoRoque coloque o código completo do script então;

Comment: o script em si é: http://prntscr.com/feoav3 a criação do cookie é setcookie("id_user", $id, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");